# Не понимаю,что за ошибка при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'
def get_html(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    return r.text
def soup(html):
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
def main():
    url='https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'
    soup(get_html(url))
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 11, in main
    soup(get_html(url))
  File "C:/Users/Антон/PycharmProjects/doesntmatter/venv/dDos.py", line 8, in soup
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\Антон\PycharmProjects\doesntmatter\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 216, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: а что терминал показывает? что за ошибка?

Comment: Забыл указать.Вот исправил.

Comment: вам же написано в ошибке, что нету парсера lxml

Comment: а почему его нету,я устанавливал.

Comment: `pip install lxml`. Если у Вас есть виртуальное окружение, не забудьте его активировать.

Comment: я делал это,окружение активировано

Comment: Вы исполняли эту команду уже после активации виртуального окружения, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да так и есть,а что нужно как-то по другому.